# Parse: Check if object exists before fetch

Tags: php, parsing

I have a column of type array. It stores pointers to other objects.
So in my loop I have something like this:

```
foreach ($artworkArr as $a) {
    $a->fetch();
    $artworkName[] = $a->get('title');
}
```

Problem here is, `fetch` immediately throws an exception if the pointer points to an invalid object.

How can I check if the object exists before calling the `fetch` method?

Comment: Try using `try/catch` to catch these exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
foreach ($artworkArr as $a) {
    if ($a instanceof ExpectedClass) {
        $a->fetch();
        $artworkName[] = $a->get('title');
    }
}
```

Or if you don't know the `ExpectedClass`, you can use [`method_exists`](http://php.net/method_exists) on the `$a` object:

```
method_exists($a, 'fetch')
```